# How to set constant number of lags of a time series data inside sts.adfuller() function test?

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-series, statsmodels

adfuller test gives each variable a different number of lags. hence different P-value.
How to get the same p-value, and how to set the no. of lags in each variable?

Theses are adfuller test results for two variables with same size but it shows different number and lags and different p-value!

```
(-1.6111475029851472,
 0.4773732658526479,
 2,
 1139,
 {'1%': -3.4334108531807006,
  '5%': -2.862892168387536,
  '10%': -2.5674898285322496},
 -8273.914480099738)
```

```
(-25.304769346612073,
 0.0,
 1,
 1140,
 {'1%': -3.4334094211542983,
  '5%': -2.8628915360971003,
  '10%': -2.5674894918770197},
 83264.08934179449)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To force `statsmodels.tsa.stattools.adfuller` to use the desired number of lags, you need to set `maxlag` argument to the desired number of lags and then also set `autolag` argument to `None` to force it to use whatever is passed as `maxlag` as the number of lags instead of performing automated lag order search routines.